# Python f-string clarification

Tags: python, f-string

I am wondering how I could convert len of a variable consisting of a list into a string using f-string. An example is this:
`str(len(names))`.
I tried this with the curly braces like this
`{str(len(names)}`
and other variations but it doesn't work. I would very much appreciate your help. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `f'{len(names)}'`…?!

Comment: You left off the final `)` in both examples, which makes me suspect a mistake when you tried it (having failed to provide an actual [MCVE] of your attempt, we have no way to know what you actually tried).

Comment: I corrected the typo. And yes, your answer solved my problem too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward. The explicit conversion with `str` is unnecessary.

```
>>> names = ['foo', 'bar']
>>> f"{len(names)}"
'2'
>>>
```

Comment: This solved my problem.